# How to list directories with specified file in them has specified content?

Tags: command-line, grep, find

I have hundreds of directories, inside each of them is a file with name `report.ext` and this file can contain a row like

```
Beta score for best model 95.35
```

I would like to get a list of directories, where this file does exist, where it contain such row and where this row contains value greater than 95.

Is this possible from command line tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is to look for those files and print their parent directory if their content match. For instance with something like:

```
find . -name report.ext -type f -exec awk '
   /^Beta score for best model [0-9.]+$/ && $NF > 95 {
     dir = FILENAME
     sub("/[^/]*$", "", dir)
     print dir
     nextfile
   }' {} +
```

If your `awk` implementation doesn't support `nextfile`, that would print the name of the directory for each occurrence of those lines in the file.

Comment: How did you get number in $NF? I read $NF stands for number of fields. How can it be greater than 95?

Comment: In awk, using `$` means to de-reference the variable, so `NF` is the number of fields, and `$NF` is the *value* of the (last) field.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, precision: `$(n)` is to get  the `n`th _field_, `$` can't be used to _de-reference a variable_.

Comment: Is it possible to trace/debug this code somehow? Apparently it does nothing for me and I don't know why?

Comment: @Dims, most likely it's the regex (`/^Beta score for best model [0-9.]+$/`) that doesn't match. Possibly because there are trailing spaces which we don't allow for, or because they are Microsoft text files with a trailing CR character on each line. See `find . -name report.ext -type f -exec grep 'Beta score for best model' {} + | sed -n l` to see what those lines contain and how the regex should be adjusted.

Comment: I wrote script in python... Although would like to learn this awk some day :)